# Middle dot interpunct symbol on linux cpanel

Tags: html, cpanel

In my html files I am using the middle dot (interpunct) symbol e.g.
Home · About · Location

When I upload the files to cpanel (linux) server, the middle dot gets converted into a foreign symbol. How can I use the middle dot on cpanel (linux) server?

Answer (score 0):

The text editor in cpanel cannot read ·
However, if you write the interpunct as &#183 then it works.